# How do I capture carriage return in textarea

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, html

We are using a custom control text box, named as tbx.
We have added an attribute as tbx.Attributes.Add ("onkeyup="," this.value = this.value.slice(0, 2000)").

Now I want one more attribute to be added, stating that I should not allow the "$" symbol to be entered. So I want to capture the "$" in key event.

Can anyone guide me about the approach.

Thanks

Comment: And what does the question have to do with the title?

Comment: Please retitle your question, or describe how the question relates with carriage return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your Attribute properly:

```
tbx.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", "return Check(event, this)").
```

And create a javascript function like this:

```
function Check(e, obj)
{
    var length = obj.value.length;
    var key = window.event ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    if (length >= 2000) {
        obj.value = obj.value.slice(0, 2000);
        return false;
    }

    if (key == 52)
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

---

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/taRJv/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
("onkeyup="," this.value = this.value.slice(0, 2000).replace('$','')")
```

That should do it.